# Create mouse event for Mozilla

Tags: javascript

I am creating mouse event by drag and drop. It works for Chrome and Opera but i have problem with doing it in Mozilla. It writes me, that event is not define.

```
document.getElementById("cievka").src = "cievka.png";
document.getElementById("cievka").width = "65";
document.getElementById("cievka").height = "10";
document.getElementById("cievka").draggable = "true";
document.getElementById("cievka").addEventListener('dragstart', function() {
        drag(this, event);
    }, false);



function drag(target, ev) {
       ev.dataTransfer.setData('img', target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`event` isn't global in Firefox.

Use the following:

```
document.getElementById("cievka").addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
  drag(this, event);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox the event is passed to handler as a parameter. You would need to handle event variable here.

```
 function fName(e)
 {
        e = e||window.event;
 }
```

Its typical cross browser stuff

Comment: Thank you.I've realised what was problem.